# How to delete the uploaded files in the "/App_Data/uploads" folder ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, delete-file

I can upload/attach files when I'm sending message in email. The files are being stored in the App_Data/uploads folder, so when I'm trying to send multiple files it takes long time before I can send it. I think it's because the folder already have many files, so I want to delete the files in folder when it's already send in email. Please help me. I'm just new with this kind of stuff. Thank you! Here's the controller:

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public async Task<ActionResult> Index(EmailFormModel model, IEnumerable<HttpPostedFileBase> files)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {

        List<string> paths = new List<string>();

        foreach (var file in files)
        {
            if (file.ContentLength > 0)
            {
                var fileName = Path.GetFileName(file.FileName);
                var path = Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/App_Data/uploads"), fileName);
                file.SaveAs(path);

                paths.Add(path);
            }

        }

            var message = new MailMessage();
            foreach (var path in paths)
            {
                var fileInfo = new FileInfo(path);
                var memoryStream = new MemoryStream();
                using (var stream = fileInfo.OpenRead())
                {
                    stream.CopyTo(memoryStream);
                }
                memoryStream.Position = 0;
                string fileName = fileInfo.Name;
                message.Attachments.Add(new Attachment(memoryStream, fileName));
            }

            //Rest of business logic here
            string EncodedResponse = Request.Form["g-Recaptcha-Response"];
            bool IsCaptchaValid = (ReCaptcha.Validate(EncodedResponse) == "True" ? true : false);
            if (IsCaptchaValid)
            {

                var body = "<p>Email From: {0} ({1})</p><p>Subject: {2} </p><p>Message:</p><p>{3}</p>";
                message.To.Add(new MailAddress("***@gmail.com"));  // replace with valid value 
                message.From = new MailAddress("***@ymailcom");  // replace with valid value
                message.Subject = "Your email subject";
                message.Body = string.Format(body, model.FromName, model.FromEmail, model.FromSubject, model.Message);
                message.IsBodyHtml = true;
                using (var smtp = new SmtpClient())
                {
                    var credential = new NetworkCredential
                    {
                        UserName = "***@gmail.com",  // replace with valid value
                        Password = "***"  // replace with valid value
                    };
                    smtp.Credentials = credential;
                    smtp.Host = "smtp.gmail.com";
                    smtp.Port = 587;
                    smtp.EnableSsl = true;
                    await smtp.SendMailAsync(message);
                    //return RedirectToAction("Sent");
                    ViewBag.Message = "Your message has been sent!";

                    //TempData["message"] = "Message sent";
                    ModelState.Clear();
                    return View("Index");
                }

            }
            else
            {
                TempData["recaptcha"] = "Please verify that you are not a robot!";
            }
        }
        return View(model);

    }
```

Answer (score 1):

intially check for file existence then try below code

```
File.Delete("~/App_Data/uploads/XXXXX.xls");
```

Comment: Thank you for the help Sir.

Answer (score 1):

Before to send on email you have to check first ...

```
if (System.IO.File.Exists(fullPath of your file))
            {
                System.IO.File.Delete(fullPath of your file);
            }
```

Comment: Thank you for the help Sir.

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
System.IO.DirectoryInfo di = new DirectoryInfo(path);

foreach (FileInfo file in di.GetFiles())
{
    file.Delete(); 
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the help Sir.

Answer (score 0):

I strongly recommend to not use App_Data folder for storing any files , by convention is created only for storing database files.